# Adding border around a menu box

Tags: css

I have html and css that does the fly out menu. Is it possible to put a border around the fly out box.

```css
#WebPartWPQ4 {
  width: 1040px!important;
  //height: 200px!important;
  overflow: hidden!important;
}
/*edit */

#WebPartWPQ6_ChromeTitle {
  //width:50px!important;
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  z-index: 0;
}
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px
}
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul,
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 397;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  //z-index: 99;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  /* z-index: 398; */
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 0px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 170px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */

#cssmenu ul {
  width: 100px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 167px;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  color: #000000;
  //background-color: #F0F9FC;
  background-color: #FFF;
  //border: 1px solid red;
  //border-bottom: 1px solid gray;

}
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  background: #cce5ff;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 2px #888;
  border-style: solid;
}
#cssmenu ul a:link,
#cssmenu ul a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
#cssmenu ul a:active {
  color: #ffa500;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <li>
              <img alt="Find" src="http://inside.colgate.in/_layouts/15/images/siteicons/Find.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
              <ul>
                <li><a href='http://inside.colgate.in/sites/sales/Policies/Forms/RegionAll.aspx'><span>Policies/Forms</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://inside.colgate.in/sites/sales/Policies/Forms/RegionCompanyWide.aspx'><span> - Company-wide</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://inside.colgate.in/sites/sales/Policies/Forms/RegionCASpecial.aspx'><span> - CA Special</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://inside.colgate.in/sites/sales/Policies/Forms/RegionSouthWestDeepWater.aspx'><span> - SouthWest Inboard</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://inside.colgate.in/sites/sales/Policies/Forms/RegionSouthWestShelf.aspx'><span> - SouthWest Shelf</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://inside.colgate.in/sites/sales/Policies/Forms/RegionLABasin.aspx'><span> - Basin</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://inside.colgate.in/sites/sales/Policies/Forms/RegionSanJoaquinValley.aspx'><span> - Deep Valley</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span>Safety Data Sheet (SDS)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span>Safety Alerts</span></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </td>
          <td>
            <li>
              <img alt="Report/Suggest" src="http://inside.colgate.in/_layouts/15/images/siteicons/ReportSuggest.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
              <ul>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>An Incident</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>An Emergency</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>An Observation</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>A Suggestion</span></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </td>

          <td>
            <li>
              <img alt="My Stuff" src="http://inside.colgate.in/_layouts/15/images/siteicons/MyStuff.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
              <ul>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>My Training</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>My PPE</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>My Safety Committee</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - CA Special</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - SouthWest Inboard</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - LA Basin</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - Valley</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>My Floor Wardens</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - Cloverfield</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - Oklahoma</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - New York</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>Adjust My Workstation</span></a>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </li>
          </td>
          <td>
            <li>
              <img alt="Emergency" src="http://inside.colgate.in/_layouts/15/images/siteicons/Emergency.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
              <ul>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>Emergency Numbers and Guides</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - Cloverfield</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - CA Special</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - SouthWest Inboard</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - SouthWest Shelf</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - Oklahoma</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - Orleans</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - Basin</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - New York</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span> - Valley</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>Incident Management/ICS</span></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>Business Continuity</span></a>
                </li>
                <td>
                  <li>
                    <img alt="Contractors" src="http://inside.colgate.in/_layouts/15/images/siteicons/Contractors.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span>Contractor Portal</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span>ISNetworld</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span>Pocket Guidebook</span></a>
                      </li>

                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <li>
                    <img alt="Get Info" src="http://inside.colgate.in/_layouts/15/images/siteicons/GetInfo.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com'><span>Orientation Materials</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span> - Company-wide</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span> - CA Special</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span> - SouthWest Inboard</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span> - SouthWest Shelf</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span> - Basin</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span> - Valley</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span>External Links</span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='http://www.google.com/world'><span>User Guides</span></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </td>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried this but it didnt help at ul li

```
border-style: solid;
```

[image]

Comment: Try using the shorthand: `border: 2px solid #333;`?

Comment: that puts border on individual links but i wanted border around the fly out box so it does not bleed into site contents.

Comment: The `<ul>` there has `0` height, which means, the contents are not being considered. Try giving `overflow: hidden` to clear the `float`s in them and give the `border` there.

Comment: Remove the `bottom`.

Comment: I moved your HTML and CSS into a snippet in the question itself, that way both are visible in the answer, anyone can run them within the same page, and there's no need to worry about your Fiddle expiring. Using Fiddles is fine, but *always* include the code they were in, as again they can expire and thus your question becomes useless in the future.

Comment: @MattD: Thanks for the tip. I wasnt aware of the fiddle expiring items. What else I should do so the negative marking is gone from this post?

Comment: @ShawnTorres The downvote isn't likely from simply not using the Code Snippet feature here. Maybe they didn't like that you didn't include any of your HTML or CSS originally, maybe they think the question is low quality for whatever reason. I was just letting you know of a site feature that's generally recommended, and that Fiddles can, albeit not regularly, expire at some point. Regardless, *always* include the relevant bits of code in your questions to keep it useful to viewers in the future. :)

Comment: gotcha. thanks for the tips. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this remove `bottom: 0` from line `88` in the JSFiddle and add `border`.

```css
/* at line 88 in JSFiddle change this */
#cssmenu ul ul {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
/* to this */
#cssmenu ul ul {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    left: 0;
}
```

By setting `bottom: 0` you're effectively telling your dropdown menu's `ul` to have a height of `0` and therefore the border only looks like it's applied to the top of the dropdown.

Comment: PERFECT... Worked like desired. Thanks so much.